# Replace NAN with 0

Tags: jquery, math

My script is returning NAN and I want it to show 0 instead.

Using || 0 has achieved this however it now returns 100 instead of 0 for var percentQ. What is causing it to return 100?

```
$('#observationTotalRefresh').on('click', function () {

    var 
    sumP = 0,
    sumQ = 0,
    countP = 0,
    countQ = 0;

    $('.observationPositive:not(:disabled)').each(function(){
        countP++;
        sumP += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('.observationQuestionable:not(:disabled)').each(function(){
        countQ++;
        sumQ += Number($(this).val());
    });

    var percentP = 100/(1 + (sumQ/sumP)) || 0;
    var percentQ = (100 - percentP) || 0;

    $("#observationPositivePercentage").text(percentP.toFixed(0));
    $("#observationQuestionablePercentage").text(percentQ.toFixed(0));
    $("#observationTotal").text(sumP + sumQ);
});
```

Comment: `percentP` is `0`, `100 - 0` equals `100`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `|| 0` for `percentP`, you are ensuring that `percentP` is always a number. So, `percentQ` will always be `100 - percentP`; if `percentP` is 0, then `percentQ` will be 100.

Your math for percentages seems oddly fishy, though. Perhaps you wanted

```
var percentP = 100 * sumP / (sumP + sumQ);
```

instead? Then, it's simply

```
var percentP, percentQ;
if(sumP == 0 && sumQ == 0) {
    percentP = percentQ = 0;
} else {
    percentP = 100 * sumP / (sumP + sumQ);
    percentQ = 100 * sumQ / (sumP + sumQ);
}
```

Comment: That seems a little cleaner. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

At this line

```
var percentP = 100/(1 + (sumQ/sumP)) || 0;
```

`sumQ/sumP` will be `0/0` and will return `NaN`, causing the rest o the equation to evaluate to `NaN` then returning `0`.

Then at this line

```
var percentQ = (100 - percentP) || 0;
```

It will be `100 - 0`, which is `100`